# Migrating from Azure functions NET5 to NET6 - How do you register middleware now

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, .net-6.0

When migrating from .NET5 to .NET6 Azure functions how do you register middleware for HttpTriggers. IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware interface is still available but no program.cs so don't know where to register middleware.

Answer (score 0):

app.UseMiddleware(); for example in your Startup class.

Comment: There is no startup class as such in the new world. I have a class for startup using the new method to get DI but the builder is now done elsewhere
'''
e.g. MyStartupClass.cs
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Api.Server.AzureFunctions.FunctionAppStartup))]

namespace Api.Server.AzureFunctions;

public class FunctionAppStartup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddScoped<User.IUserRepository, User.SA.UserRepositorySA>();
    }
}'''